# Can't get MySQL to recognize host names?

Tags: mysql

I'm running `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'myHostname';` and on that hostname and running `mysql --host=otherServer --user=root --password` and it keeps saying access denied.

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'myHostname' (using password: YES)
```

Does MySQL not recognize hostnames?

Comment: Have you set a password on that account? Try adding `IDENTIFIED BY 'password'` to the end of your `GRANT` statement.

Comment: @JeremySmyth - That was it, thanks!  Can you post that as an answer?

Comment: Your wish is my command!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, each account is the combination of a user *and* the hostname, so the password on this new account is not necessarily the same as that of other `root` accounts.

Ensure you've created a password on the new account by adding an `IDENTIFIED BY` clause:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'myHostname'
   IDENTIFIED BY 'new_password';
```

If the account already has a password, the `IDENTIFIED BY` clause *overwrites* that password.